# Classic ASP Application Object returns always Null

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to create a Cache in classic ASP by using [ASP Application Object](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_applications.asp).
It turns out that every time I try to read the stored value, it returns null.
I'm using Windows 7 with IIS version 7.5.7600.16385.

What do I suppose to do?

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<head>
</head>
<%
Application("test") = "Hello World!"
dim i
For Each i in Application.Contents
  Response.Write(i & "<br>")
Next
dim k
For Each k in Application.StaticObjects
  Response.Write(k & "<br>")
Next
%>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: You will need to show a read/write example, and by null you mean *Nothing* ?

Comment: Yes, nothing.... Null = Nothing.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524512%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Your example should be:

```
For Each i in Application.Contents
  Response.Write(Application(i))
Next
```

That is: enumerating the collection returns the keys rather than the values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm NooB and I feel more Noob then ever now.
What I was doing wrong is that the correct way to read the value is

```
  Response.Write(Application("test"))
```

and to associate is

```
  dim anything
  anything = Application("test")
  Response.Write(anything)
```

i'm sorry for make you all waste your time! Thanks!